# Dynamically SELECT a column based on value of row at first of month

Tags: sql

The following query:

```
  SELECT Confirmed, Interim, Declared, Date    
    FROM Interest_Hist                         
   WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-12-04'          
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Returns the following sample data:

```
Confirmed   Interim   Declared   Date
Y           0.314     0.0788     2019-08-01
            0.317     0          2019-08-02
...
            0.245     0          2019-08-31
            0.222     0.219      2019-09-01
            0.198     0          2019-09-02
...
Y           0.50      0.454      2019-12-01
            0.51      0          2019-12-02
            0.52      0          2019-12-03
            0.53      0          2019-12-04
```

Where on the first of the month, `Confirmed` = Y, I need to return the `Declared` column for that month.

*Note, `Confirmed = Y` will only exist on the first of the month.  That column is blank in all other cases*

Otherwise, I need to return each `Interim` column for the month.

Thus far, I have been able to return the `SUM` of either column, but not the individual values.

```
SELECT                                                                   
   CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN IRc_Confirmed = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0   
     THEN Interim                                     
     ELSE Declared                                     
  END AS Rate                                                    
 FROM Fund_Interest                                                
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-08-01' AND '2019-12-04'           
GROUP BY                                                                   
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Date), 0), Interim, Declared                 
ORDER BY                                                                   
  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Date), 0)
```

**The expected output given the data at the top is as follows**

```
0.0788
0
...
0
0.222
0.198
...
0.454
0
0
0
```

Comment: What is the "interim value for the month".  I see a bunch of different values.

Comment: There will be a different interim value for each day of the month.  I need to return each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me way longer than it probably should have.

```
SELECT IIF( MAX(Confirmed) OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Date, 112)) = 'Y', Declared, Interim) Interest_Rate 
FROM Interest_Hist
WHERE DateBETWEEN '01-AUG-2019' AND '04-DEC-2019'         
ORDER BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all the year months where the first day is Y:

```
SELECT year([date]) as yr, month([date]) as mo
FROM fund_interest
WHERE DAY([date]) = 1 and confirmed = 'Y'
```

This gives you a list of years and months where there is a Y on the first eg Aug 2019

Now make it a cte and left join it back to your data on year and month, and where the join succeeds return declared else interim:

```
WITH x AS(
  SELECT year([date]) as yr, month([date]) as mo
  FROM fund_interest
  WHERE DAY([date]) = 1 and confirmed = 'Y'
)

SELECT
  CASE WHEN x.yr IS NOT NULL THEN f.declared ELSE f.interim END AS something
FROM
  fund_interest f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN x ON x.yr = year(f.[date]) AND x.mo = month(f.[date])
```

All of the rows of different days from Aug 2019 and Dec 2019 will succeed in the join. They will have a NOT NULL yr value and hence the declared will show. For all Sep 2019 rows there is no match in the join (Sep 2019 is not returned by the query in the CTE), yr is null, interim shows instead

For a better idea of what is going on do a SELECT *

If you want to use just a single column the EOMONTH function could be used to return a consistent date every month. Replace MONTH with EOMONTH. Remove calls to YEAR from the query

Do not use reserved words like DATE as column names, by the way

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to group by month and year and then join to your original table (Interest_Hist) on the month and year parts of your date field. You can then select the Interim or Declared value using a simple case statement

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT DATEPART(month, DateFld) Mnth, DATEPART(year, DateFld) Yr, 
  MAX(Confirmed) ConfirmedVal
  FROM Interest_Hist  
  GROUP BY DATEPART(month, DateFld), DATEPART(year, DateFld)
 )
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN c.ConfirmedVal= 'Y' THEN interest.Declared ELSE interest.Interim END
 FROM Interest_Hist interest
 INNER JOIN CTE c ON
 DATEPART(month, interest.DateFld) = c.Mnth AND
 DATEPART(year, interest.DateFld) = c.Yr
```

You can see the query in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f808cc/3)